# Maven unpack-dependencies of a plugin dependency

Tags: maven

How do I run `dependency:unpack-dependencies` for dependencies specified inside the `<plugin>` section?

I have three packages containing executables and some other stuff, let's call them `parent`, `child` and `consumer`. **`child` is dependent on `parent`**. In order to build consumer, I need to get `child` and all its dependencies (i.e. `parent`), unpack their contents and do some stuff.

**What I have now works, kind of:**

When the dependency on `child` is declared "globally" in `<project>`, the unpacking works as expected. However, that means that the resulting `consumer` package depends on `child`, which I do not want. The dependency has to be solely for its creation, not usage.

When I move the dependency into the `<plugins><plugin>` section, it is ignored by `dependency:unpack-dependencies` (`dependency:unpack` processes and unpacks it fine, but that is not transitive)

What am I missing? Thanks

---

Maven knows about the transitive dependency `child` -> `parent`. When I delete the whole local repository and run only this POM, `parent` is downloaded.

---

A very crude diagram of the situation below. Green artifacts are needed for creation of the final artifact (and not needed to use it afterwards), therefore dependency on them only belongs to the  section. Blue artifact is needed for the usage of final artifact, therefore it has a dependency on it.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why would you like to unpack plugin dependencies ?

Comment: It is not a java project. In the parent package there is a protobuffer compiler, in the child a plugin for said compiler. Using this pom I want Maven to download the plugin of a specified version, which in turn downloads the compiler it depends on. Using exec plugin I then run the compiler with some parameters and then pack the created artifacts into a jar.We are targeting multiple platforms using multiple languages, Maven seems to me like a good tool for that.(Some of it is java, in which case that is without any problems.For non-java it is still okay to use with some caveats - like this one)

Comment: Can you be more specific what `protobuffer compiler` means?

Comment: It's a Google-developed tool for serializing and deserializing data, in short. That is not important. The bottom line is that my .jars contain executables which I need to unpack and then run (in bash, cmd, whatever, based on the platform). I am unable to get the unpacking of transitive dependencies working, however.

Comment: Thinking a little bit...Why not packaging the executables and deploying them separately and adding them as dependency to the plugin which means they will during runtime on the classpath of the plugin...and they will downloaded automatically ...

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I updated the question with a diagram of the situation. Perhaps I was confusing when I referred to a "plugin". In fact there are two artifacts, both containing executables and some libs, which need to be unpacked so that an `exec` plugin can use them. Instead of "plugin" I will use the term "extension" to avoid confusion. Those executables are compiled from C++ source and then packaged as Maven artifacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your unpacking works as expected when you specify dependency for the whole project, perhaps you should just keep it that way. Instead of moving it to plugin dependencies you can simply instruct Maven to not include it transitively when other projects depend on your project. There are two ways to do it:

1. Specify `<scope>provided</scope>` - this will tell Maven that dependency is needed for compilation, but is expected to be available at runtime by other means (such as application server providing it or you bundling it).
2. Specify `<optional>true</optional>` - this will prevent dependency from being transitively resolved by other projects depending on your project. Instead, they will have to specify it explicitly, if they want it.

Comment: The first suggestion does work, but feels a bit hackish. If nothing better turns up, I will use that.

Comment: @MartinMelka to be honest, I would consider it the correct approach. This is because dependencies are a more broad concept than just "other libraries should be downloaded and added to classpath". Your project clearly does something with the other projects, so they are some type of project dependencies, just not runtime dependencies.